# Kubernetes API server manual start

Tags: kubernetes

I am following the conference demo here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3KtEAa7_duA&list=PLsClnAJ27pEXdSwW2tI0uc0YJ2wzxJG6b

My aim would be to start all kubernetes components by hand to understand its architecture better, however I stumble upon this proble when I start the api server:

```
root@BLQ00667LT:/home/user/kubernetes# ./kubernetes/server/bin/kube-apiserver --etcd-servers=http://localhost:2379
W0704 11:13:35.394474    4924 services.go:37] No CIDR for service cluster IPs specified. Default value which was 10.0.0.0/24 is deprecated and will be removed in future releases. Please specify it using --service-cluster-ip-range on kube-apiserver.
I0704 11:13:35.394558    4924 server.go:391] external host was not specified, using 172.17.89.222
W0704 11:13:35.394569    4924 authentication.go:527] AnonymousAuth is not allowed with the AlwaysAllow authorizer. Resetting AnonymousAuth to false. You should use a different authorizer
E0704 11:13:35.395059    4924 run.go:74] "command failed" err="[service-account-issuer is a required flag, --service-account-signing-key-file and --service-account-issuer are required flags]"
```

I suspect the kubernetes verson used by the tutorial is different from mine, mine being much more recent as the video is from 2019 and I downloaded the latest Kub. v1.28

Would you know what's wrong or if there is any other tutorial or learning path I could follow ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank for asking,

If you want to know more about kubernetes architecture you can try this

https://github.com/kelseyhightower/kubernetes-the-hard-way from Kelsey

it's easier because it has code that you can copy and paste, but you need to adapt with your environment, such as subnet, route and network interfaces.

because naturally it's for google cloud.

Good luck